# Xamarin : On screen rotation the OptionMenu Icon is repeated twice

Tags: android, xamarin, screen-orientation

I am using the options menu which I am putting on the navigation bar using **MenuInflater**

after when the activity is created when I try rotating the screen then I see two Icons instead of a single icon.

I am trying to search for the solution about how to handle screen rotation event.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

here is the activity.cs

```
        [Activity(Label = "Menu", Icon = "@drawable/Icon", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
    public class MenuNavigation : ListActivity {
   string[] items;
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);
       items = new string[] { "Chat", "News", "Events", "Member List", "My Profile", "About Association" ,"About Application"};
       ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
   }

   public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
   {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main, menu);
            return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
}
```

and menu/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
  android:id="@+id/action_logout"
  android:icon="@drawable/logout"
  android:orderInCategory="100"
  android:title="Log Out"
  android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: You need to provide some actual code for us to help you with this issue. At least some minimal reproduction steps.

Comment: @Cheesebaron added code for activity.cs and menu.xml in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was searching for the solution on developer.xamarin -> [Handling Rotation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/)

I found the solution to my own question.
All I had to do was to:

```
[Activity(Label = "Menu", Icon = "@drawable/Icon", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

**ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation**

This has solved the problem but I think there might be a better solution, so any other solutions are appreciated.